# React native asyncstorage cannot get data

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm starting my react-native project with npm start. On my emulator I have installed expo to view my application. Also I'm using http://ip:19001/debugger-ui/ to debug my application in google chrome.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I can't get any data from asyncstorage. Can you please give me some tips how to correct this problem.

In one of my activities I store data with;

```
 storeDataInAsync1(idSchool,year) {
      try {
            //await AsyncStorage.removeItem('user');

            AsyncStorage.setItem('dateRange', this.props.range);
            AsyncStorage.setItem('idSchool', idSchool);
            AsyncStorage.setItem('school_year', year);

          } catch (error) {
            // Error saving data
          }
    }
```

My call to this method;

```
async saveMyProfil() {
    var formData  = new FormData();
    formData.append('id_school',this.props.idSchool);
    formData.append('school_year', this.props.year);





    await fetch(`${api.url}/my_profile/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        body: formData,
      }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
          console.log('Response: ' + JSON.stringify(json));
          this.storeDataInAsync1(json.id_school,json.school_year);

          //_storeData(json.id_school,json.school_year);
          //this.doStuff(json.id_school,json.school_year);
        })
        .catch((error) => {

        });
  }

  back() {
    //this.storeDataInAsync();
    this.saveMyProfil();
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
  }
```

In another activity there is method to retrive data;

```
_retrieveData = async () => {
      try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('idSchool');
        const year = await AsyncStorage.getItem('school_year');



        if (value !== null && year !== null) {
          // We have data!!
          console.log('Id School: ' + value);
          console.log('Year: ' + year);
        }
       } catch (error) {
         // Error retrieving data
       }
    }
```

I call _retrieveData in;

```
componentDidMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);

        this._retrieveData();




    }
```

Comment: You can only store data in `AsyncStorage` in a string format. Try putting breakpoints and check if the values are actually stored or not. Also, you can't use `await` together with `.then()`. Simply use `fetch().then().catch()` and remove the `async await`.

Comment: How to put breakpoints?? I'm developing my react in sublime editor...Also hwo to check values if is stored or not...?

Comment: Are you saying you're developing a React Native app without ever having gone through the guidelines/docs? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

Comment: I have done that :)

Comment: This is the quickest way to debug: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#chrome-developer-tools

Comment: I'm already using chrome to debug my app :)

Comment: Then you should be able to put breakpoints and check whether values are stored or not. Try and see.

Comment: Where in chrome debugger can I see stored data?? I can't find anything

Comment: I have an error:
Error: Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes. Instead, make sure to clean up subscriptions and pending requests in componentWillUnmount to prevent memory leaks

Comment: https://egghead.io/lessons/react-using-the-chrome-debugger-to-set-breakpoints-in-react-native

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native AsyncStorage not getting the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799924/react-native-asyncstorage-not-getting-the-value)

Comment: I know...But I still could not get any data...Where in debugging can I see asyncstorage?